# Syncing & saving models and Collections with Backbone - what is the response?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, backbone.js

When syncing a model:

```
myModel.save();
```

or saving an entire collection:

```
Backbone.Collection.prototype.syncCollection = function (options) {
    Backbone.sync("create", this, options);
};
myCollection.syncCollection();
```

I use MongoDB on the server-side, which stores documents with the '_id' attribute. I set the id format when I define my Model:

```
myModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    idAttribute: '_id' //mongoDB uses _id as identifier
    //more stuff here
});
```

At the very least, I need to get the _id attribute into the client-side app, so that the MongoDB documents can correctly be addressed once they are created.

What should the server response to such api calls be? I don't see anything about that in the documentation.

Comment: If I understand you try to update the attribute "_id" with the value assigned by Mongo, if that is the case take a look to the method 'parse', http://backbonejs.org/#Model-parse, this allow you to set the values from the backend response in your model.

Comment: I noticed all my models have a cid instead of an _id. My question: What do I do on the server-side after receiving a POST and updating the DB?  How does the client side receive the _id from the server? Do I output the model in JSON?

Comment: Yes, for example, this could be the response from your server for the save method: {"_id": 123456789} and this automatically will be updated on the model if the .save() method was used, if your response is in a different format, for example {"status": "success", "response": {"_id": 123456789}} you can use the parse() method to extract and return the JSON to be updated in the model.